# I compiled a program in fortran using GCC but the executable outputs files to the user path of my system instead of where the program is located

Tags: gcc, path, fortran

The program is placing the files to the path `Users/username/` instead of the `Oil and Cells folder`. Can I fix this issue with the compiling command?

I used `gfortran -o Planar_Surfactant Planar_Surfactant.f` while inside of the `Oil and Cells` folder to compile the executable.

`~ % /Users/username/Documents/BMEN\ Research/Oil\ And\ Cells/Planar_Surfactant ; exit;`

this is what shows up when I run the program along with some information about the base values.

I'm pretty new to fortran coding so I'm not quite sure what to try or how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths in the program are relative to the current working directory, which starts off as the directory where the program is launched, not where the program binary happens to be located.

(This is per se not specific to Fortran.)

Comment: How would I change the directory where the program is launched?

Comment: @GavinPaull Are you asking how to use the shell? Like `cd directoryname` , `cd ..`, and so on.

Comment: Oh I understand now, I launched the program from terminal and that fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @GavinPaull if this answer solved your issue, please gently accept it as the solution. Cheers :)